# Flutter WiFi connection results in connection via app (Android)

Tags: android, flutter, wifi

I am developing an app that needs to directly connect to a WiFi-Direct Printer (Brother HL-L5210DW) . For now the OS is Android 13+ only, iOS is not relevant here.

When using the system dialog i can connect to the printer's network ("Direct-eO...") and print using the [printing](https://pub.dev/packages/printing) plugin implemented in the flutter app.
The problem resolves around this connection, see the 'Connected without internet' in image below.

[image: direct connection]

Checking the connection data using the [network_info_plus](https://pub.dev/packages/network_info_plus) plugin. The connection looks like this:

```
[SSID] "DIRECT-eOSNAG-02_BR5029"
[Gateway] 192.168.118.1
[getWifiBSSID] 02:41:--:--:--:-- (edited)
[getWifiIP] 192.168.118.100
[getWifiSubmask] 255.255.255.0
```

All the above is working as expected.

The requested workflow asks for the user to be able to switch networks to the printer without using system dialog, though...

So I implemented it using the [WifiForIoTPlugin](https://pub.dev/packages/wifi_iot) (among others I tried in the process) to connect to the printer.

```
  Future<bool> connectToNetwork(String ssid) async {
    var res = await WiFiForIoTPlugin.connect(ssid,
        password: kNetworkPass,
        security: NetworkSecurity.WPA,
        withInternet: false);
    return res;
  }
```

Resulting in a connection that states it's connected via the app.
[image: indirect connection image]

Now the printer can not be reached anymore, as there seems to be some kind of network issue I do not understand.

Network details now look like this:

```
[SSID] "DIRECT-eOSNAG-02_BR5029"
[Gateway] null
[getWifiBSSID] 02:41:--:--:--:-- (edited)
[getWifiIP] null
[getWifiSubmask]
```

For completion's sake here are the permissions as per AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NEARBY_WIFI_DEVICES" />
```

I assume this is some kind of android security feature, but it seems weird that I can not reach devices on the network - not even the gateway (printer) the device seems to be connected to.

What am I missing here ? Is there a way to connect programmatically to a network with the same result as using the system dialog ?